# Why does Python use different quotes for representing strings depending on their content?

Tags: python, string, quotes, double-quotes

In Python 2.7, I noticed that `repr(s)` (with `s` being a string) behavior differs depending on `s`'s content.

Here is what I mean:

```
In [1]: print repr("John's brother")
"John's brother"

In [2]: print repr("system")
'system'
```

Note the *different* quotes type in both case.

From my tests it seems that whenever `s` contains a `'` character, the represented string is quoted with `"` **unless** the string also contains an (escaped) `"` character.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
In [3]: print repr("foo")
'foo'

In [4]: print repr("foo'")
"foo'"

In [5]: print repr("foo'\"")
'foo\'"'
```

Now I understand it makes no difference since `repr` is not to offer any guarantee about the exact output format but I'm curious as to why the Python developers decided those things:

- Why is there two ways of quoting strings ?
- Why bother with the specific logic for representing strings that contain quotes ? After all it makes things like `doctests` a bit more difficult to write.

Comment: Python is all about making it easy for developers to use. It's so *so* much easier to write a string that `"has parrot's, I mean quotes"` in them or `'"Just use this", I said'`. And way easier to read than `"\"Just use this\", I said"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python tries to give the most "natural" representation of the string it's `repr`-ing.

So, for example, it will use `"` if the string contains `'` because `"that's the ticket"` looks better than `'that\'s the ticket'`.

And there are actually four ways to quote strings: single quotes — `'` and `"` — and triple quotes — `"""` and `'''`. There are these four methods because it's nicer to to be able to write strings naturally without escaping things inside them.